# timeout when uploading JSON using Firebase Storage blob.upload_from_string(...)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Everything has been working smoothly for months but I recently have started receiving a timeout error when I try to upload a JSON file to Firebase Storage as shown below:

```
from firebase_admin import storage

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob('feed_items.json')
...
blob.upload_from_string(json_string, content_type = 'application/json')
```

This is the stack trace:

```
blob.upload_from_string(json_string, content_type = 'application/json')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2107, in upload_from_string
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1925, in upload_from_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 3262, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my_app.appspot.com/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 400, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

The JSON file size is ~400 KB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to upload a very small blob? Let's say, less than 1KB.

Comment: Exactly the same

Comment: Are you sure it's a timeout error? The `timeout=timeout,` line in the stack trace doesn't necessarily indicate that the request is timing out. A 400 Bad Request response usually means the request was received in time, but the server doesn't think it's properly formatted.

Comment: I am not but it is the only error that I get and JSON file seems to be alright. What else it could be?

Comment: Maybe the API has changed recently. Try upgrading to the most recent version of the cloud library and see if that helps.

Comment: Just updated gcloud and firebase_admin and still getting the same error

Comment: The content of the server response might contain more diagnostic information. Try to catch the exception, and print `the_exception.response.content`.

Comment: `b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Invalid Value",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Invalid Value",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "invalid"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n'`

Comment: I tried with: `blob.upload_from_string('something to test')` instead but I'm getting the same error message. It seems like I can read the content of `feed_items.json` but I cannot write anything on it. I don't understand what's going on

Comment: Hi @DanielGarcíaBaena I would recommend you to reach out to the developers from the API on the [Github Repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues) and raise an issue there. Due to the fact that this seems to be an issue within this part and that your application just stopped to work, they should be able to provide you with better assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally contacted with Google Cloud technical support and they noticed that this behavior could be caused by the way the blob object is invalidated or times out. They suggested using `blob.reload()` method as below. `blob.reload()` gets a solid reference to the blob object in storage, and this seems to fix every state change caused by other methods.

```
from firebase_admin import storage

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob('feed_items.json')
...
blob.reload()
blob.upload_from_string(json_string, content_type = 'application/json')
```